# Two COM Dlls with Different GUIDS, AppID and TypeLib but same name

Tags: dll, com, guid, rgs

I have two COM Dlls with same name and entries in .rgs files except the GUIDs (ie. CLSID, APPID, and TypeLibID. The idl file contains different GUIDs too.
Can both the components coexist ? I have Application A which uses the one COM component and another uses the second one. Can both call their respective COM components ?

Comment: As long as their installers don't overwrite each other's executable files, yes.  Class and interface names do not matter, only the GUID is used.  Changing the GUIDs like that is *required* when the author changes his code.

Comment: Does the ProgID in the rgs file need to be different ?

Comment: There are normally two, a version specific one like Foo.Bar.2 and a default one, like Foo.Bar that refers to the latest version.  Not everybody uses this scheme. The ProgID is normally only used by code that uses late binding so the versioning accidents are not as fatal.